# Load AngularJS Data to table on automatic refresh

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, refresh

I have a table which shows values from db through AngularJS:

```
<div class="container wrapper" ng-controller="DbController">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>NUMĂR ORDINE</th>
        <th>NUME CLIENT</th>
        <th>ACȚIUNE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in details| filter:search_query">
        <td>{{detail.id}}</td>
        <td>{{detail.nume_client}}</td>
        <td>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editInfo(detail)" title="Preiau client"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

I can`t find a function that will refresh the table at a few seconds automatically, to reload the new data. Is there a way to do this without refreshing the page manually or clicking a button?

I have a function which refreshes a span but I don`t know how to adapt it to Angular:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshDiv() 
{
    $("#refresh").load("includes/assets/receptie_clienti/databaseFiles/get_client_count.php");

} 
window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 1000);
</script>
```

And HTML:
`<span id="refresh">0</span>` //Initial value is 0 and it changes when new values are adeed to database

**LE: Fixed like the answer selected:**

Modified AngularJS Controller:

```
var ClientsApp = angular.module('ClientsApp',[]);
ClientsApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http','$interval', function($scope,$http,$interval){
// Refresh the data automatically to get clients details from the database
$interval(callAtInterval, 1000);
function callAtInterval() {
    $http.post('includes/assets/receptie_clienti/databaseFiles/get_clients.php').success(function(data){
// Stored the returned data into scope 
$scope.details = data;
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to refresh details use $interval in your controller.

```
$interval(function() {
  $scope.detail = 'call your getData service here';
}, 1000);

ClientsApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', $interval, function($scope,$http,$interval){
  ...
}
```

Comment: $interval is an id?

Comment: This is Angular controller:
`var ClientsApp = angular.module('ClientsApp',[]);
ClientsApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

// Function to get employee details from the database
getInfo();
function getInfo(){
// Sending request to EmpDetails.php files 
$http.post('includes/assets/receptie_clienti/databaseFiles/get_clients.php').success(function(data){
// Stored the returned data into scope 
$scope.details = data;
});
}`

Comment: $interval is a angular service provider, like window.setInterval. you can  inject it at your controller

Comment: I did it like this: var ClientsApp = angular.module('ClientsApp',[]);
ClientsApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http','$interval', function($scope,$http,$interval){
$interval(function() { $scope.detail = 'includes/assets/receptie_clienti/databaseFiles/get_clients.php'; }, 1000);
...
in my Angular js script.

Comment: Nothing happens after I adeed that code in angular script. No error in console.

Comment: you should try fetch or something to get the data from the url 'includes/assets/receptie_clienti/databaseFiles/get_clients.‌​php', then give the data to details

Comment: I figured it out as you said. I will post the correct answer. It worked as a charm. Thank you!